# Trouble reinstalling Python(x,y)

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, uninstallation

Python(x,y) was previously installed on my computer but I had to reinstall it due to some reasons. The problem occurs when I try to install it again. I get a message at the beginning of the installation where it says "could not write updated path to HKLM." I have cleared almost the entire registry of everything that mentions python in any way, deleted all python folders and deleted python from the system path but the problem will not go away.

Any solutions?

Comment: My computer is running on w7 64 bit if that is of any use.

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the machine? You likely will need to right click the Python installer, and select `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: Tried that, doesnt help.

Comment: Well, that's odd then. The installer is trying to write to a key in the registry that it's unable to. If you're a fairly advanced user, I would recommend user, I would recommend using Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to track the installer. It will show you exact file and registry keys that are being accessed, as well as the final key which is erroring. Here's a youtube video on how to use that too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH_JqB_XwWg